# Widget is null inside initState

Tags: flutter

It's the first time a use Flutter (2.8.1) and I'having problems trying to undestrand what's going wrong.

I have a Stateful widget like this:

```dart
class SimpleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Type2 aValue;
  const SimpleWidget({Key key, @required this.aValue}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _SimpleWidgetState createState() => _SimpleWidgetState();
}

class _SimpleWidgetState extends State<SimpleWidget> {
  Type1 color;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    color = widget.aValue; // <-- widget is null
  }
  ...
}
```

that I call in this way:

```dart
List<Type1> something = await showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    print('currentElement.aValue: ${currentElement.aValue}'); // not null
    return SimpleWidget(aValue: currentElement.aValue);
  },
);
```

Why is `widget.aValue == null` in `initState()`? How can I solve it?

Comment: Where is `widget.color` declared and received?

Comment: you get `aValue` because you define `aValue` in `SimpleWidget `. Neither `color` or `size` defined in `SimpleWidget `, when you call `widget.XXX`, it will be `null`

Comment: Your code does not match and should probably not even compile. There are no `color` or `size` properties on your widget and you do not set them.

Comment: Sorry @Jungwon, @SamChan, @nvoigt. I made a mistake. Wrong copy and paste. `color` should be `aValue`. I updated the main message

Comment: Did you turn off null-safety? It cannot be null... at least your compiler said so and I'm inclined to believe them.

Comment: change `final Type1? aValue`  and  `color = widget.aValue!;`

Comment: @Jungwon Please don't take guesses. Why would that change anything? It would make it worse...

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You have tons of copy and paste errors and omissions and any best guesses based on uncompilable code is just not what this site was made for.

Answer (score 1):

There are some error in your coding;
The first one is construction of `SimpleWidget`

```
const SimpleWidget({Key key, @required this.aValue}) : super(key: key);
```

when you call like `SimpleWidget(aValue: currentElement.aValue);` It will should error like `key can not be null`. You can use `?` to make it nullable. Also, `@` should be remove, it is a syntax error

The correct one looks like

```
const SimpleWidget({Key? key, required this.aValue}) : super(key: key);
```

The second one is in `SimpleWidgetState`

You can change `Type1 color;` to `late Type1 color;`
**Or** make it nullable.
For more details, you can check [flutter codelabs](https://dart.dev/codelabs/null-safety)